# Executing pdftk.exe with arguments in process

Tags: c#, process, exe, pdftk

Currently struggling to get this process working:

```
        const string pdfkPath = "pdftk.exe";

        var paths = new List<string>();

        paths.Add(@"C:\test.pdf");
        paths.Add(@"C:\testje.pdf");

        var cmd = String.Join(" ", paths) + " cat output " + @"C:\lel.pdf";

        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = pdfkPath;
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = cmd;
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.Start();

        p.WaitForExit();
```

Executing the exe file with the arguments using command line works, so what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found it ourselves! The problem was the output being directly on the C:\, folder between fixed it